# Send image url with form submit

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have contact form that sends an image div in a client mail

```
<form name="form" method="post" action="mail.php" id="myForm"> 
</form>
```

The form is submitted by an input type submit

```
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" id="capture" />
```

My php for sending email is

```
<?php
include("auth.php");
//message
$message = $_POST['msg'];
$username =$_REQUEST['username'];
$surname =$_REQUEST['surname'];
$name= $_REQUEST['name'];
$filename = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$imageurl  = 'http://panosmoustis.netai.net/barcodeimage/'.$filename.'.png';
//mail body - image position, background, font color, font size...

$body = "Dear $surname  $name
Thank you for your Pre-registration for Global.
Please print the attached e-ticket with your personal barcode and bring it to the reception of the exhibition.
This barcode includes data about you which is required during registration. Having this barcode will considerably speed up the registration process
Organizing committee.\n".



$body = "Print e-ticket
              $imageurl.\n".





//to send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set:
$headers='MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: <http://panosmoustis.netai.net/>' . "\r\n";
$to = $_POST['mail'];
$subject = "EXPRESS REGISTRATION (Global)";
//mail function
$email = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
if(!$email) { 
echo "Error sending email"; 
} else {
echo "Your email was sent successfully.";
}
?>
```

Then i have an ajax function for saving an dynamically created image on the server

```
<script>
 $("#capture").click(function() { 
html2canvas([document.getElementById('printableArea')], {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        var imagedata = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        var imgdata = imagedata.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
        //ajax call to save image inside folder
        $.ajax({
            url: 'save_image.php',
            data: {
                   imgdata:imgdata
                   },
            type: 'post',
            success: function (response) {   
               console.log(response);
               $('#image_id img').attr('src', response);
            }
        });
    }
})
 });
</script>
```

My php file for saving image on the server

```
<?php
$imagedata = base64_decode($_POST['imgdata']);
$filename = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
//path where you want to upload image
$file = '/home/a7784524/public_html/barcodeimage/'.$filename.'.png';
$imageurl  = 'http://panosmoustis.netai.net/barcodeimage/'.$filename.'.png';
file_put_contents($file,$imagedata);
echo $imageurl;
```

My problem is that i want to send imageurl to email client on form submit 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
$imageurl  = 'http://panosmoustis.netai.net/barcodeimage/'.$filename.'.png'
```

Here you used string concatenation.

But here you didn't:

```
$body = "Print e-ticket   $imageurl.\n".
```

You just need to do the same thing you did when you created the $imageurl with a random file name :)

Comment: i already tested to do it and gives wrong image url because the image contains client information

Comment: Can you post the error, and tell us when it gives you the error?